# How to open Bluetooth Settings from a WPF Application?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-10-desktop

I am developing a Windows 10 WPF application and I am using **32feet.net** for working around with the Bluetooth. Now I am facing a problem to Turn Off/On the Bluetooth programmatically so the alternative that I have found is to Access the **"Action Center"** from my WPF app and turn off /on Bluetooth.
So my question is ,how would I be able to access the page of my choice from My WPF app ?

I have to turn off Location also , it would be great if my application allows me to open the **Location** page present under **Settings->Privacy->Location**  or the **Action Center**.

Any help shall be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.FileName = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(
    @"%localappdata%\Packages\windows.immersivecontrolpanel_cw5n1h2txyewy\LocalState\Indexed\Settings\en-US\AAA_SettingsPagePCSystemBluetooth.settingcontent-ms");
startInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
Process.Start(startInfo);
```